# React use different component if a component is overflow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, overflow, responsive

I am trying to check if a component if overflow, and then use different component (responsive). The content is dynamic so I can't use specific breakpoints.

Here is the react component:

```
componentDidMount(){
  const element = this.element;
  this.setState({
    overflow: element.offsetHeight > 50
  });
}

componentWillMount(){
  window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
}

componentWillUnmount(){
  window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
}

handleResize = () => {
  const element = this.element;
  this.setState({
    overflow: element.offsetHeight > 50,
  });
};

render() {
  return (
    <div ref={(el) => {this.element = el}}>
      { this.state.overflow ? smallComponent : bigComponent } 
    </div>
  );
}
```

The problem is the overflow state that changes because if overflow is true, then is will use the smallComponent, then the next render it will be false because is has used the smallComponent. So it is not responsive when I resize the window, and it will jump from bigComponent to smallComponent back and forth.

Is it a more "elegant" way to solve what I am trying to do ?

Comment: You can't use `window.innerHeight` in your event listener instead, and always go with e.g. `window.innerHeight <= 756`?

Comment: No, because the content is dynamic, and it is supposed to support different screen sized. So the content can be everything from 50px to 1000px width. And of course the screen can be tablet, pc, 4k etc.